# PHP static function self:: in joomla JFactory class explanation?

Tags: php, class, function, joomla, self

Hi I'm looking at the code of Joomla and trying to figure out what exactly happends in this function.

index.php makes a call to function

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

jfactory.php code

```
public static function getApplication($id = null, $config = array(), $prefix='J')
{
    if (!self::$application) {

        jimport('joomla.application.application');

        self::$application = JApplication::getInstance($id, $config, $prefix);
    }

    return self::$application;
}
```

application.php code..

```
public static function getInstance($client, $config = array(), $prefix = 'J')
{
    static $instances;

    if (!isset($instances)) {
        $instances = array();
    }

    ....... more code ........

    return $instances[$client];
}
```

Now I cannot figure out in function getApplication why is self:$application used.

```
self::$application = JApplication::getInstance($id, $config, $prefix);
```

$application is always null, what is the purpose of using this approach. I tryied modifying it to

```
$var = JApplication::getInstance($id, $config, $prefix);
```

and returnig it but it doesn't work.

I would be very glad if someone with more knowledge could explain what is happening here detailed as possible. Many thanks.

Comment: `self::$application` is not related to `$application`.

Answer (score 4):

`self::` is used to access static members of a class.

So in this case, `self::$application` is used to cache the application object within JFactory to avoid multiple calls to `JApplication::getInstance` which is more expensive.

For more info on statics, see [Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: I still don't get it. This is some kind of a singleton pattern, as I understood, right? But what makes me confusing is actually $application, when I tried to change to self::$app it generates an error, why?

Comment: @Carbon6 Yes, it's a singleton pattern. What about $application? What and why would you want to change to self::$app?

Comment: Maybe this will sound stupid, but why it HAS to be called self::$application = ... why can't it be just as a variable $var = JApplication::getInstance... As I tried it and in that case it doesn't pass the value? I don't want to change it :) just understand it.

Comment: I can be renamed to anything. But if you just set it to a local variable $var it wouldn't be "cached" until the next function call. Therefore self:: is used. It could be named self::$app, but you'd have to change to that name in many places.

Answer (score 1):

`getApplication()` - Returns a reference to the Global JApplication
object. [***Read more***](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory_Class)

`self::$member` for static members to be accessed.

Here is an explanation as far I can understand.

```
if (!self::$application){ //<-check for the $application static variable of the the class

jimport('joomla.application.application');        
self::$application = JApplication::getInstance($id, $config, $prefix);

//if it does not exist get a new instance otherwise nothing happens because there is no else part 
}

return self::$application; //<- return the object(new one or the existing one)
```

What this does is if $application exist a function call is saved. If not get a new instance. [***Read more***](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/create-template/jfactory-get-application). Hope this helps you out.

Comment: So in the CMS $application is going to be either 'site' or 'admin' right?

Factory works for either, but one at a time. So you need to say which one you are dealing with.

So for whichever application you are in go find the static members of the class.

Try var_dumping $application and $app.

Comment: Var_dump($application) returns always null, before and after the call to function, var_dump($app) returns an object JSite with all params.

Comment: refer the link. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/create-template/jfactory-get-application